# Nodejs JSON property undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to access properties within a JSON GET response using the request nodejs module.

When i receive the response, i cannot seem to print the specific properties. Every time i try to print a property, I get an error saying its undefined.

I tried stringifying and parsing the JSON, but both did not work. Thanks in advance.

```
var request = require("request");

//The search query
var query = "TGI fridays";

//path of http request
var path = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query="+query+"&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyA-adbJAXBmOTGINrhWHskm4d7UU9dgnOU";


//function to print the json
var parser = function(text){
    console.log(text);


}
//http request with callback
request(path,function(error, response, body){
    parser(body.next_page_token); //a property from the json that comes up as undefined
})
```

heres some of the json

```
    {
   "debug_info" : [],
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CjQsAAAAM5EDuFB7u9bIQ_3KeBsa894EjYv4ca3GVN45O2cBPWUaDFkebH7r_WQy2Jf-QqZZEhDUipJwL4YXDtanJ0euTGe4GhTs6PW_jM0Ops33vWwD-5aGsk7giQ",
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "403 Camino Del Rio South, San Diego, CA, United States",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.760091,
               "lng" : -117.161897
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
         "id" : "29f39df87b93cf8b98062fdccc877a61fb45925a",
         "name" : "TGI Fridays",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 782,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBdgAAAFw5rZL8KjKfsBudSV-fNyRQUy5kflYnWJUrsN8PHzVsrP8v3R5eCKkRJOUj8fXnAtXnZZ34G5BRoNys7mLd0QJ3LEj-tLeY9LSs4B9jOyNpaNAszEZDh9kyQkfWr4POMxqwKCYN5gxFsMB4-NvGoG3sFZaOOySOKs6vVNPPL9fVEhCKe8eESOot42-Zxm4MBPPaGhSsiMuJbzuIzOpqTcEHEsL1c6GXYg",
               "width" : 1146
            }
         ],
         "price_level" : 2,
         "rating" : 3.2,
         "reference" : "CnRpAAAAp9SAKVfthj4gk3rSghMmI3_ZJaGTzGPhVtDsdtSyG3WunYPrYEN7dAA0iEmmsTLx3ANN9FAZZ6bVNnyUxWAwEFe8a-IsTSJZwNTYq-6fMujMZJgjTWgSSWo5LXy88NdccA3l-PQ2pX2Dnz4SnLy0dhIQ_hVBBDjk8QV2oOS-THq3BBoUKOSwQjmKFn5KeJq43p4JIkANwPU",
         "types" : [ "bar", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]
      },
```

Comment: @ruakh `parser(body.next_page_token);` looks like such an attempt. @user2758113 perhaps `parser(response.next_page_token)` belongs there?

Comment: @JanDvorak parser(response.next_page_token) didn't work. still getting undefined. Thanks though.

Comment: @JanDvorak: When I posted my comment, that line was just `parser(body);`. The OP has improved the question since then. :-)  (I'll delete my comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Body is a string.  Try:

```
//http request with callback
request(path,function(error, response, body){
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    parser(body.next_page_token); //a property from the json that comes up as undefined
})
```

Result (a very large string):

```
CjQsAAAAls3nW7k5vyODIeouCv_HT_PBhB9s7KNftqBRiDWtJR3RY_KOLthW4TFj-2HNlnezEhDiq73Z83kFvtpQqWfuBb-AGhT6yoVHZHNe1EmM3UWe34jfs65oHg
```

Note: you could also use this form to tell `request` that you are expecting json:

```
request.get({url: path, json:true},function(error, response, body){
    parser(body.next_page_token); //a property from the json that comes up as undefined
})
```